# Making a Boolean column in a JXTreeTable editable

Tags: java, swing, jxtreetable

I have a [`JXTreeTable`](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html) structure with 5 columns and I have to make the last one (of Boolean type) editable.

I've tried anything, googled for hours, I searched here on SO and I've found similar questions but they're not helping in my specific case (that's because they gave answers about issues with `JTrees` or simple `JTables` and not with `JXTreeTable` component).

I've already specified the `getColumnClass(int column)` method in my tree model to make the boolean cells in the last column be rendered as `JCheckBoxes`, and the `isCellEditable(Object node, int column)` method to return the column and make it editable.

I'm actually populating that column with a query that reads a file from a database and sets some of those cells to true if they meet the requirements.

Here's the link to what my GUI actually looks like:

[image: Interface]

Let me know if you need some pieces of my code to see, and thanks in advice!

Here is the tree construction:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode albero = initTree();

final JXTreeTable binTree = new JXTreeTable(new MyTreeModel(albero));

Highlighter highligher = HighlighterFactory.createSimpleStriping(HighlighterFactory.BEIGE);
binTree.setHighlighters(highligher);

binTree.setShowGrid(false);
binTree.setShowsRootHandles(true);

binTree.setEditable(true);

configureCommonTableProperties(binTree);
binTree.setTreeCellRenderer(new TreeTableCellRenderer());
```

The definition of the TreeModel:

```
public class MyTreeModel extends AbstractTreeTableModel {

    private String [] titles = {"Utente", "Radice Menù", "Programma", "Descrizione", "Abilitazione"};

    public MyTreeModel(DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
        super(root);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        if (column < titles.length)
            return (String) titles[column];
        else
            return "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(Object node, int column) {
            return column == 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        if (column == 4 )
            return Boolean.class;
        else
            return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(Object arg0, int arg1) {
        if(arg0 instanceof TableRowData) {
            TableRowData data = (TableRowData)arg0;
            if(data != null) {
                switch(arg1) {
                  case 0: return data.getUtente();
                  case 1: return data.getRott();
                  case 2: return data.getProgramma();
                  case 3: return data.getDescrizione();
                  case 4: return data.getFlag();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(arg0 instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode dataNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)arg0;
        TableRowData data = (TableRowData)dataNode.getUserObject();
        if(data != null) {
            switch(arg1) {
              case 0: return data.getUtente();
              case 1: return data.getRott();
              case 2: return data.getProgramma();
              case 3: return data.getDescrizione();
              case 4: return data.getFlag();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(Object arg0, int arg1) {
         if(arg0 instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
             DefaultMutableTreeNode nodes = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)arg0;
             return nodes.getChildAt(arg1);
         }
         return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount(Object arg0) {
        if(arg0 instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode nodes = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)arg0;
            return nodes.getChildCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        if(arg0 instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode && arg1 instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) arg0;
            return parent.getIndex((DefaultMutableTreeNode) arg1);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node)   {
        return getChildCount(node) == 0;
    }

    return null;
}
```

And the class that implements the get/set methods for the row data:

```
public class TableRowData {
    private String utente = null;
    private String rott;
    private String programma;
    private boolean flag;
    private String descrizione;
    private boolean isRoot;

    public TableRowData(String Utente, String Rott, String Programma, String Descrizione, Boolean Flag, boolean isLeaf) {
        this.utente = Utente;
        this.rott = Rott;
        this.programma = Programma;
        this.flag = Flag;
        this.descrizione = Descrizione;
        this.isRoot = isLeaf;
    }

    /**
     * @return the isRoot
    */
    public boolean isRoot() {
        return isRoot;
    }

    /**
    * @param isRoot the isRoot to set
    */
    public void setRoot(boolean isLeaf) {
        this.isRoot = isLeaf;
    }

    public String getUtente() {
        return utente;
    }

    public void setUtente(String Utente) {
        this.utente = Utente;
    }

    public String getRott() {
        return rott;
    }

    public void setRott(String Rott) {
        this.rott = Rott;
    }

    public String getProgramma() {
        return programma;
    }

    public void setProgramma(String Programma) {
        this.programma = Programma;
    }

    public Boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(Boolean Flag) {
        this.flag = Flag;
    }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, we need to see your code. Just the stuff which creates the structure should be enough. Try to avoid including too much code which populates the table with data.

Comment: Dunno if I did it properly, but i've added all the code related to the structure creation.